# What is the source of the "That boy needs therapy" song from Frontier Psychiatrist?

Tags: lyrics, identify-this-sample

The song "Frontier Psychiatrist" by The Avalanches contains a sample of what sounds like an excerpt from a movie:

> That boy needs therapy, psychosomatic
>   That boy needs therapy, purely psychosomatic
>   That boy needs therapy
>
> Lie down on the couch, what does that mean?
>   You're a nut, you're crazy in the coconut
>   What does that mean? That boy needs therapy
>   I'm gonna kill you, that boy needs therapy

Can anyone identify it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's from the comedy sketch “Frontier Psychiatrist” by Johnny Wayne and Frank Shuster.

[Source](http://genius.com/4439542)

[And the mp3](http://blogfiles.wfmu.org/LG/Wayne_and_Shuster_-_Frontier_Psychiatrist.mp3)

Answer (score 2):

It's actually from multiple sources. The bit about Dexter being truant, Mr. Kirk, and Miss Fishbourne is from John Waters' movie Polyester (1981). The "list" is also in the wikipedia article about the track.

Comment: That's not what he was asking about.